# Change text in masterpage based on the language selected

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

In my master page along with the search box I have label "Search".  Now it is hard coded and 
is working fine.  But when I change language the text should change to "Rechercher".  This should happen in master-page, how can I achieve this.  There few mote other texts which also needs to be changed based on the language change.

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an [EncodedLiteral](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.encodedliteral.aspx) control with an out of the box Resource string. If your master page was based on an out of the box master page like v4.master, you should be able to see many examples of this control in use.

To include a language aware label for search, I might use the following:

```
<SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" 
    text="<%$Resources:wss,mobile_navigation_search_text%>" 
    EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/>
```